# glGetUniformLocation returning the same value for all programs

Tags: android, c++, ios, opengl-es-2.0

We have several different opengles2.0 shaders, each of them use different uniforms. We use glGetUniformLocation to get the position to write the data to for each uniform.  However, this means that when we switch shader programs, then sometimes for example, we are writing the cameramatrix to one location, sometimes to another, all depending on which uniforms are defined for that shader. This means we can't easily cut down on redundant shader uniform uploads by checking if the value to upload has changed, as we may well need to reupload it to overwrite a value written by a different shader for a different uniform.

While I know it would be possible to include the same uniforms in each shader program, whether they are used or not, would glGetUniformLocation then return the same position back for each program ? Or, for example, might the shader compiler remove unreferenced uniforms and bunch up the rest, causing each shader to have its uniforms in different locations. This is for IOS and Android.

Thanks

Shaun

Answer (score 1):

Uniforms are per-program state, so it doesn't matter whether their locations differ for different programs because if you want to avoid redundant uniform changes then you need to track the uniforms on a per-program basis rather than on a global basis like you might do with DirectX9.

And yes, OpenGL might remove unused uniforms or otherwise rearrange them even if you had the exact same ones in every compilation unit.

Comment: OK, so if one program returns location "10" from glGetUnifiormLocation for something and I write a float value of "99" there, then I switch to another program which has returned location "10" for something else, and I write "88" to that location, while using the second program,  then the "99" will still be set for the original program if I switch back ? i.e. are they unique locations, or are some shared ?

Comment: Yes, the 99 will still be there for your first program when you switch back.